# Set multicolor tab bar icon instead of monochrome icon

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uicolor, uitabbaritem

I need a way to have multicolor tab bar icons, but for some reason, iOS keeps drawing the icon in a monochrome fashion.

I tried various methods such as including this line of code: `tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName:"routineIcon").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)` in the `viewDidLoad` of my first view controller but I had no luck.

Is there any way I can retain color information in a tab bar icon without making it monochrome? It looks a thousand times better when it's multicolored.

Thanks,

Harish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new `UITabBarItem` and assign it to the `tabBarItem` property of your view controller.

```
// In viewDidLoad()
self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Hello world!", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "routineIcon").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), tag: 0)
```

Also, if you're using an assets catalog (which you should), notice that in your asset settings you have a *Render As* setting which you can set to *Always Original*.
You can then ommit the `.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)` when using your image.

```
// In viewDidLoad()
self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Hello world!", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "routineIcon"), tag: 0)
```

There is also an initializer that takes a selected image if you have one

```
// In viewDidLoad()
self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Hello world!", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "routineIcon"), selectedImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "routineIconSelected"))
```

---

Note : As a general rule, modifying system `UIBarItem` objects (`UITabBarItem` for tab bars and `UIBarButtonItem` for navigation bars or tool bars) often doesn't work and you need to create a new one.
System bar items are the one created with `init(tabBarSystemItem:tag:)` (for `UITabBarItem`) or `init(barButtonSystemItem:target:action:)` (for `UIBarButtonItem`).
When using a storyboard, you can decide to use either a system bar item or a custom one.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! I hope the line of code I had above eventually works as it'd be cool to modify certain things like that instead of creating a whole new one